# Finite volume reconstruction techniques

Tags: finite-volume

For a cell-centered finite-volume calculation, with a nontrivial stencil (either using an unstructured grid or a strongly non-uniform structured grid), what are the main techniques for reconstruction of function values and derivatives on cell faces? What are their advantages and disadvantages, e.g., compared to the polynomial interpolation? Is there a book or a recent review article covering this?

Comment: Maybe this is a good start: https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/mohlb_01/postscript/finvol_script.pdf

Comment: @MPIchael Thanks a lot, that's a great review article, with many useful references there.